# Using Process Monitor, how do I trace a process and its children?

Tags: windows, process, process-monitor

Using *SysInternals [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)* (`procmon.exe` or `procmon64.exe`), how do I trace a process with a given PID and its child processes?

My first (naïve) idea was to include both "PID is 1234" and "Parent PID is 1234" predicates -- only to find out that they are joined using AND rather than OR, and thus are mutually exclusive.

Is it possible to somehow join filters with OR?

Comment: I usually use ProcMon the way that I exclude each and every process (exclude by path) I am not interested in. Therefore what remains is what I am interested in, no matter how many different processes are contained in this process set. You could do it the same way.

Answer (score 3):

From *Process Monitor Help* (`procmon.chm`):

> Process Monitor
>
> - **OR**s together all the filters that are related to a particular attribute type and
> - **AND**s together filters of different attribute types.

Let's say that I want to trace `PowerShell.exe` process and its child processes. Then launch `powershell` from Window Run Dialogue (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) as

```
cmd.exe /c "title="mycmd" & tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "powershell\.exe" & echo --- & start "" "powershell" & >NUL timeout /T 2 & tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd powershell\.exe" & pause"
```

Let's say that the `mycmd` window output looks a follows:

> ```
> "powershell.exe","5384","Console","1","88 752 K","Running","PC\user","0:00:01","Windows PowerShell"
> ---    
> "powershell.exe","5384","Console","1","88 752 K","Running","PC\user","0:00:01","Windows PowerShell"
> "cmd.exe","5008","Console","1","4 488 K","Running","PC\user","0:00:00",""mycmd" "
> "powershell.exe","4344","Console","1","84 468 K","Running","PC\user","0:00:01","N/A"
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Then, I can set filter in *Process Monitor* as

```
Parent PID is 4344                # childs of newly created powershell.exe instance
Parent PID is 5008                # childs of ephemeral cmd.exe i.e our powershell.exe
Process Name is not conhost.exe   # service utility for any console application
```

In other words:

(`Parent PID is 4344` **OR** `5008`)  **AND** (`Process Name is not conhost.exe`)

---

The <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> command meaning:

- `cmd.exe /c "title="mycmd"`: start an auxiliary (ephemeral) command prompt instance, set its  title and then perform following tasks:

  - `tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "powershell\.exe"` list current (present) PowerShell instances
  - `echo ---` print a line separator
  - `start "" "powershell"` launch a new PowerShell instance
  - `>NUL timeout /T 2` wait a small amount of time
  - `tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "mycmd powershell\.exe"` list current instances of PowerShell and our auxiliary `cmd.exe`
  - `pause"` wait for user's response

Comment: Thanks, your response is really good, but if we’re talking about the **existing** (long-running) children, the same can be accomplished from within `procmon.exe` via the Process Tree action (`Ctrl`+`T`). From there, you can select a process and all its children, and multiple PIDs will indeed be OR’ed. What I’m asking about is a different use-case: consider I’m about to debug a batch file (`.cmd`), and the PID of its parent `cmd.exe` is already known while any child PIDs are not as the script hasn’t been run yet. In other words, I’m looking for a Linux `strace` equivalent.

Comment: Any batch file (`.cmd`) does not run as a child process of a `cmd.exe`   
 instance but *inside* it (and its parent is _usually_ `explorer exe` with **many other childs**).  So the key idea is launching the _main_ traced process (`powershell.exe` in my answer) from an _ephemeral_ process which has _no other child_.  If you want to trace `cmd` and its childs then swop `cmd` and `powershell` in `Win`+`R` command i.e. use `powershell` as that ephemeral wrapper, [mutatis mutandis](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mutatis_mutandis).